Как в psql вывести список таблиц командой \d, если в базе несколько схем
В базе есть несколько схем, в данном случае public и bookings.
Требуется вывести список таблиц из схемы bookings.
\d выведет список таблиц схемы public,

\d bookings.table_name выведет конкретную таблицу из схемы bookings.

Вопрос: как вывести список таблиц из схемы bookings?

SET search_path TO bookings; -- Выбираем в качестве текущей схемы схему bookings

или можно так
SET search_path = bookings;  -- Выбираем в качестве текущей схемы схему bookings

и далее
\d

Выводится список таблиц из требуемой схемы.

P.S. для того чтобы узнать список имен схем в текущей базе данных - необходимо ввести команду:
\dn


P.P.S. Чтобы узнать имя текущей схемы - необходимо ввести запрос:
SELECT current_schema;



\dt bookings.*

все таблицы в схемах public и foo:
\dt public|foo.*

так же допустимый вариант \dt *.* но уже много шума, т.к. включает в себя и системные каталоги.
Аналогично применимо к \d  и прочим \d(что-то)
